# How can I escape double quotes in my JSON responses?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have the below code which transforms a datatable into a JSON string, the JSON I'm getting from my WCF service looks like this;

```
   [{"id":"7c6c2d6b-416c-4535-95ba-b49a9f0c008b","title":"hello","description":"world","complete":true,"DependsOnTask":"63d47a78-ba4d-4740-9f61-9247dd9d5e82","id1":"63d47a78-ba4d-4740-9f61-9247dd9d5e82","title1":"another","description1":"example","complete1":false,"DependsOnTask1":null}]
```

and the conversion code looks like this;

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,Formatting.Indented);
                        string cleanjson = json.Replace("\"", "");
                        return json;
```

the problem is that I can't deserialise the JSON properly on the client recieving that response because the JSON has extra double quotes in it, and I have been unable to remove them using string.replace.

is there another way to do this at all?

Thanks in advance :)

*******UPDATE*********

This is the code I'm using on the client

```
 private void LoadTasks()
        {
            // get the todo list items
            ToDoService.ToDoServiceClient client = new ToDoService.ToDoServiceClient();

            try
            {
                //List<ToDoService.ToDoItemContract> toDoItems = client.GetToDoItems("").ToList();
               //List<string> ItemsWithDependantTasks = new List<string>();

                var Items= client.GetAllDependantTasks();
                List<string> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(Items);



                dlTasks.DataSource = list;


                dlTasks.DataBind();

                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: Log error
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your json string is OK...

Comment: What seems to be an array of data is shown as duplicated numbered properties. Why are you doing that ? Are these 2 records ?

Comment: Btw, `"\"` is shown by visual studio and the debugger, it is not actually part of the data, so you don't need to replace it.

Comment: yes these are seperate records, that's just what json.net automatically does for duplicate records but the information in those records is different

Comment: Show us **exactly** what `client.GetAllDependantTasks()` returns - not an escaped view of the debugger (hint: copy the data using the text visualizer).

Comment: @Lucero I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no extra quotes, the JSON data is valid (you can verify yourself by pasting the JSON data to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ for instance).

However, how do you expect JSON.NET to deserialize that into a list of plain strings? This needs to be deserialized to some dictionary, a `JObject` or an entity with matching properties.

Comment: so instead of deserialising it into a list of plain strings, i should deserialise it into a dictionary?

Comment: @ReeceCottam That really depends on what you're going to do with the data afterwards. The point is that your JSON data contains an array of object(s) with properties, not plain strings, so trying to deserialize to a string does not make sense and has to fail.